# Binding between the two columns in the DataGrid

Tags: wpf, binding, wpfdatagrid

I have a DataGrid which is binded to a list with two properties.

First column in the DataGrid is DataGridTemplateColumn and it has ComboBox inside.

Second column in the DataGrid is DataGridTextColumn and it is binded with a converter.

Whenever i change the  combobox value in the first column, the second column converter must be triggered. So based on some calculation in the converter i can return the value to second column

how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can route that through your bound source, bind the selected item of combobox to your bound data and then bind the selected object to column 2 using converter. Share the selecteditem between two columns and for the second column use the converter in binding, so it gets triggered.

**Corrected copy paste error in column 2 binding**,

Something like this,

```
Presenter / ViewModel
class DataSource : INotifyPropertyChanged {
  // raise PropertyChanged when required
  public ObservableCollection<string> Columns1Values {get;set;}
  // raise PropertyChanged when required
  public string SelectedColumn1Value {get; set;}
}
```

View

```
<dg:DataGrid
    Name="sampleDG"
    ItemsSource={Binding DataSourceObject}>
    <dg:DataGridWidget.Columns>
        <dg:DataGridTemplateColumn
            Header="Column 1">
            <datagrid:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Label Content="{Binding Path=SelectedColumn1Value, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </datagrid:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <datagrid:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ComboBox
                        ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Column1, Mode=TwoWay}"
                        SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedColumn1Value, Mode=TwoWay}"
                    />
                </DataTemplate>
            </datagrid:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        </dg:DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <dg:DataGridTextColumn 
            Header="Column 2"
            Binding="{Binding Path=SelectedColumn1Value, Converter={StaticResource selectedConverter}, Mode=TwoWay}}">
        </dg:DataGridTextColumn>
    </dg:DataGridWidget.Columns>
</dg:DataGrid>
```

Comment: But how the converter will get triggered everytime when you change the combobox? What is that Binding path "Column" in the DataGridTextColumn?

Comment: Sorry my mistake (copy paste error), column 2 should be bound to SelectedColumn1Value as this is the member you need to share between columns and thus when the Column1 binding updates it, its change will trigger your converter to be called for column 2 binding. For Column 2 the Binding mode can be OneWay if you don't intend to modify the selection from column 2 to column 1.